# Delete duplicates where the value of another column in the same row = 0

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with ~30k rows of data and 20 columns. A lot of the values in column B are duplicates, and I would like to delete those duplicates. The problem I have is that even though column b may be a duplicate, that row's data in the rest of the columns are not necessarily a duplicate, so it's important that we only delete the row if the value in column B is a duplicate AND the value in column M = 0.

Is there a way to do do this for each row in the worksheet (the worksheet name is Test)? I imagine it involves "For Each...", but i don't have a lot of experience with that and haven't been able to find any other macros that can complete this task. Let me know if you need me to elaborate on what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sort the data on column M descending and then Data ► Remove Duplicates on column B. Remove Duplicates always removes the duplicate from the higher row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way in VBA, that queries your spreadsheet like a table.  You'll have to adapt the RunQuery() method for your particular case, because I don't know your column names.

This assumes the following:

1. Your worksheet is laid out like a table, with column names in row 1, and data below it
2. You've saved your workbook before running this code

In my particular workbook, I have a Column labeled "Category", one labeled "Types", and I've added a column called "DeleteMe".

```
'Adapt RunQuery for your particular needs
Sub RunQuery()
    'Change this SQL statement to reflect your particular need
    SQL = "SELECT [Category], [Types] FROM %table(0)% GROUP BY [Category], [Types] HAVING Count(*) > 1"

    'Change "Sheet2" to your sheet name
    Set rs = QuerySheet(SQL, Sheet2)

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        SQL = "UPDATE %table(0)% SET [DeleteMe]='x' WHERE [Category]='" & rs!Category & "' AND [Types]='" & rs!Types & "'"
        'Again, change Sheet2 to your sheet name
        QuerySheet SQL, Sheet2
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub

'You don't need to change this function
Function QuerySheet(sSQL, ParamArray Worksheets())
    Dim oSh
    Dim sConn, n

    On Error GoTo QuerySheet_Err
    Set QuerySheet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Worksheets(0).Parent.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"

    n = 0
    For Each oSh In Worksheets
        sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "%table(" & n & ")%", "[" & oSh.Name & "$]")
        n = n + 1
    Next
    QuerySheet.Open sSQL, sConn
    Exit Function

QuerySheet_Err:
    MsgBox "Error in QuerySheet(): " & Err.Description
    End
End Function
```

[Source](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/frontpage/vba_library/#QuerySheet_Run_SQL_queries_directly_on_Excel_worksheets)

The code updates the "DeleteMe" column with an x.  Now, you can sort by the "DeleteMe", and delete the rows (or write a simple VBA statement to do that).

**Your** RunQuery() method will need to look more like this, replacing "column B" and "column M" with the names of the fields in your sheet's header row:

```
    ...

    'Change this SQL statement to reflect your particular need
    SQL = "SELECT [column B] FROM %table(0)% WHERE [column M] = 0 GROUP BY [column B] HAVING Count(*) > 1"

    'Change "Sheet2" to your sheet name
    Set rs = QuerySheet(SQL, Sheet2)

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        SQL = "UPDATE %table(0)% SET [DeleteMe]='x' " & _
           " WHERE " & _
           IIf(IsNull(rs![column B]), _
               " [column B] IS NULL", _
               " [column B]='" & rs![column B] & "' ") & _
           " AND [column M]=0"

        'Again, change Sheet2 to your sheet name
        QuerySheet SQL, Sheet2

    ...
```

**Note**: Sometimes you get debug errors when you change the names of the worksheets from "Sheet1" to something else... Haven't worked that issue out yet.  But this works well for "Quick N' Dirty" queries.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a shot!

Comment: Saw your comment on the other answer - updated the 2nd code snippet to handle NULLs in column B

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to frequently repeat the same process, you can also just filter those rows that match your criteria and manually delete them.

Provided your data is sorted based on column B, you can add a formula in column M that compares the values for each cell in column B with the value above and below to identify duplicates.

The following formula will check if cell B matches value above **OR** below **AND** if column M=0 and result in True/False.
=AND(OR(B2=B1,B2=B3), M2=0)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The one issue is that there are also some values in column M that are blank so they get sorted to the bottom; however those still might need to get deleted if the value in column L = 0. Is there any way to complete this task using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this without VBA:

Add a column with formula

```
=B1&IF(M1=0,"",RAND()*9999999)
```

This will create a unique entry if M1=0

Copy paste the new column to values

Do the regular 'Remove duplicates' routine, based on the new column.

Remove the new column